# Ansys parallele job on Slurm Cluster stuck without error or exit message

Tags: cpu, batch, parallel-processing, slurm

I am working on a Slurm Cluster, executing Ansys (V18.2) jobs in a parallelized way. **Large jobs (meaning large solver files) often stuck with out error message or exit message, the jobs keep running until timeout is reached.** 
Due to large job size, the solver files are written/saved not incore (in RAM) or on the node's scratch SSD but on the **cluster /data storage**. There, I clearly see if the job is stuck by no change in the "date modified" information of the solver files.

Typical error message I experienced were "node fail" or undefined exit message that I related to leak of memory. But those do not occur right now.

**Strangely, if running the same job again this might happen at a different time point or (if I am lucky) not at all.**

What I tried so far:

- **Reducing number of requested CPUs** somehow increases the likely hood
  that the job will complete. But due to specified max job time I need
  parallelization
- MPI types (intel, platform mpi) with no result
- dedicated storage partition (no significant difference)
- incore VS out of core request (anyway solver always switches to out of core)

I am glad about any advice on how to reduce senseless computational effort by re-runnign jobs number of times which is also time consuming for our project.

PS: Way smaller jobs (e.g. 3 times smaller number of DOFs) never experience this problem and I can use the full number of cores per node that is also the max number allowed with my Ansys licence (16 cores)